# export wordpress posts in xls or csv format within a specified date range

Tags: csv, wordpress, xlsx

I have a WordPress site which has lot of posts and i want to export those posts in xls or csv format within a specified date range.

There is calendar option which shows posts but no export functionality.

There is tools export but that does in xml format.

I found various plugins that do export posts in XLS format but none of them lets me filter by date range

Comment: @akshay paghdar - it does not let me specify a date range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using wordpress version 3.5.2 than you can try to use this plugin. http://wordpress.org/plugins/export-to-text/

even you are using updated version than you can also check it once.

Comment: is it possible to have this functionality in frontend instead? thanks